I upgraded the Google Play Billing library version 5 to 7 and got an error
I upgraded the Google Play Billing library version 5 to 7 and got an error.
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.

A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable

enter image description here
enter image description here
enter image description here
I can't fix this error, please help me. thank you very much
i tried using gpt chat but couldn't solve this problem

Please don't post text in screenshots.

Did you try to clean the project and then build it again?
